# trying to scrape from long PDF with different table formats

Tags: r, pdf, data-extraction, pdf-scraping, tabulizer

I am trying to scrape from a 276-page PDF available here: https://www.acf.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/ocse/fy_2018_annual_report.pdf

Not only is the document very long but it also has tables in different formats. I tried using the extract_tables() function in the tabulizer library. This successfully scrapes the data tables beginning on page 143 of the document but does not work for the tables on pages 18-75. Are these pages unscrapable? If so why?

I get error messages that say "more columns than column names" and "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

```
child_support_scrape <- extract_tables(
  file   = "C:/Users/Jenny/Downloads/OCSE_2018_annual_report.pdf", 
  method = "decide", 
  output = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As texts in pdf files are not stored in plain text format. It is generally hard to extract text from a pdf file. The following method provide an alternative method to extract the table from the pdf. It requires the `pdftools` and `plyr` package.

```
# Download the pdf file as a variable in R
pdf_text <- pdftools::pdf_text("https://www.acf.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/ocse/fy_2018_annual_report.pdf")

# Focus on the table in page 22
pdf_text22 <- strsplit(pdf_text[[22]], "\n")[[1]]

# Reformat the table using "regular expression"
pdf_text22 <- strsplit(pdf_text22, " {2,100}")

# Convert the table in a data frame
pdf_text22 <- plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(pdf_text22, function(x) as.data.frame(t(matrix(x)))))
```

Additional formatting may be required to beautify the data frame.

Comment: Thank you for your help s20012303. Your solution works. The data needs a little cleaning but at least my computer and I can both read it.